# Send Syslog message into file and directly on the console at the same time

Tags: ros, syslog

I am writing a ROS Node, and I am currently using ROS_INFO and ROS_ERROR for messages that are shown directly on the console. Now I want to switch to syslog and I want to use the syslog function for C. 
That already works fine when I duplicate the log message and send it with syslog and ROS_INF/ERROR at the same time. But now I always have two line codes for the same error message in the code. Is there an easy way to show the syslog messages also on the console?!
Br Harald

Answer (score 0):

Seems like rosconsole has multiple backends and you might be able to change that at compile time. Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1036#issuecomment-298123291)